# Why does my vue-tel-input country code dropdown not format properly in my vuejs app?

Tags: vue.js, input, dependencies, yarnpkg, vue-tel-input

I installed the vue-tel-input library https://vuejsexamples.com/international-telephone-input-with-vue/ in my vuejs project. Why does my input field look like this with no country flags and no country code?

[image: ![enter image description here]

This may be related to an error I saw when installing the yarn library...

```
error /Users/xxx/Documents/Work/software/xx/xx/node_modules/vue-tel-input: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: cd docs && npm ci --prefer-offline
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/xxx/Documents/Work/software/xx/xx/node_modules/vue-tel-input
Output:
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: docs: No such file or directory
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwkyP.png
```

Here is my relevant component code...

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <VueTelInput v-model="phoneNumber" v-bind="bindProps"></VueTelInput>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 import { VueTelInput } from 'vue-tel-input'
 import 'vue-tel-input/dist/css/component.css'
 import 'vue-tel-input/dist/css/sprite.css'

 export default {
   name: 'CuiRegister',
   computed: {
     ...mapState(['settings']),
     loading() {
       return this.$store.state.user.loading
     },
   },
  components: { VueTelInput }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize the vue-tel-input in the main.js of Vue
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tel-input
refer  this link

Comment: you don't have any bindProps in your code as you don't have a data method please remove it or make a data method and define the bindProps.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use available props for the vue-tel-input library available here: https://iamstevendao.github.io/vue-tel-input/documentation/props.html

To add country flags and country codes you'll need to use **dropdownOptions.showFlags** and **dropdownOptions.showDialCodeInList** props resepectively. Remember **dropdownOptions** is an object hence you can include the prop as shown below:

```
<VueTelInput v-model="phoneNumber" :dropdownOptions = "{showFlags:true, showDialCodeInList:true}" v-bind="bindProps"></VueTelInput>
```

Here is a demo for the same: https://iamstevendao.github.io/vue-tel-input/